# How to add a new array to an existing npz file in a standard way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a function which writes an array to a compressed **.npz* file:

```
def save_a(file):
    np.savez_compressed(file, a=[[1, 2, 3]])
```

I want to make a function calling the function `save_a()`, then adding another array to the file (e.g. with metadata):

```
def save_a_b(file):
    save_a(file)
    np.savez_compressed(file, b=[len(save_a.__name__)])
```

Sadly, when I try to use the function `save_a_b()`, I have the former array overwritten:

```
buffer = io.BytesIO()
save_a_b(buffer)
buffer.seek(0)
with np.load(buffer) as fh:
    for name in fh:
        print(name, fh[name])
```

I need to implement it without use of:

- private methods,
- hacking the *.npz* format unless its specification is warranted to be backward compatible in the future.

I prefer solution applicable both to file objects and to `str` paths.

Comment: You have a compressed zip archive.  Within the archive (which you can view with a OS level archive tool) are `.npy` files, one for each array.  You could use `np.save` to create a new `npy`, and use an OS tool to added it to the archive.

Comment: You might think of using compressed hdf5 files (internally zipped) instead, they are easy to modify?

Comment: @hpaulj I may also use the `zipfile` module, but I would like to avoid hacking the format and stich to `numpy` API.

Comment: @Okapi575 change of format is not an option. Decision of The Architect.

Comment: So you know about `zipfile`.  That's what `np.lib.npyio._savez` uses.  Its use of `format.write_array` is essentially `np.save`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
import numpy as np

def save_a(filename):
    np.savez_compressed(filename, a=[[1, 2, 3]])

def save_a_b(filename):
    save_a(filename)
    data = np.load(filename)
    np.savez_compressed(filename, b=[len(save_a.__name__)], **data)

npzfile = '/tmp/test.npz'
save_a_b(npzfile)

print(list(np.load(npzfile).items()))
```

Putting it into a function:

```
def show_npzfile(npzfile):
    data = np.load(npzfile)
    for key, value in data.items():
        print(key, value)

def add_data(npzfile, overwrite_old=True, **new_data):
    data = dict(np.load(npzfile).items())
    if not overwrite_old:
        new_data, data = data, new_data
    data.update(new_data)
    np.savez_compressed(npzfile, **data)

print(f'content of "{filename}":')    
show_npzfile(filename)

add_data(filename, c=np.random.randint(0, 10, 10))

print(f'content of "{filename}":')    
show_npzfile(filename)

add_data(filename, c=10, d='asdf', overwrite_old=False)
print(f'content of "{filename}":')    
show_npzfile(filename)
```