# Why isn't this appending to a numpy file?

Tags: numpy

I'm trying to write as I go using `numpy` with multiple writes to `savez_compressed` - however, as you can see below, only the last write, `b` in this case, is preserved. Can `savez_compressed` not be appended to?

```
import numpy as np

with open("f.npz",'wb') as f:
    np.savez_compressed(f, a=[1,2,3])
    np.savez_compressed(f, b=['q', 'r', 's'])

b=np.load('f.npz')
print(b.files)
```

Comment: Do you understand the zip archive nature of a npz?  Does `savez` document appending?

Comment: Your code doesn't show us anything about what was saved.  It's just code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61488293/901925

Comment: `np.savez` does not implement multiple writes to a file, even if it is already opened.  Details of that are buried in its interaction with `zipfile.ZipFile`.  Keep in mind the `f.npz` is a `zip archive`, with individual arrays written to `npy` files with the `np.save` protocol.  In previous SO I've mentioned the possibility of writing `npy` files, and using OS or zip tools to add them to the archive, but haven't seen working examples.  In any case, `appending` is not documented anywhere in `numpy`.  (appending to `npy` files is possible, but also undocumented.)

Comment: Thanks, it's not supported, ok, will find another way.